# How to print the status if it is neither true nor false in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named `ProjectSite` and another named `ManagerRemark` which takes a decision boolean value.  `ProjectSite` has many `ManageRemark`.

The default value of `decision` is nil.

How can I print status as "Pending" when there is no `ManagerRemark`?

Here is the code:

```
<% project_site.manager_remarks.each do |manager_remark| %>
  <% if manager_remark.decision == false %>
    <td><%= 'Rejected' %></td>
  <% elsif manager_remark.decision == true %>
    <td><%= "Approved" %></td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= "Pending" %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to use correct grammar; Capitalization, spelling and punctuation are important here and can affect how your quickly your question is answered because your effort put into asking a good question affects our willingness to help. "[ask]" and the linked pages will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if a case block is easier to read in this example

```
<% project_site.manager_remarks.each do |manager_remark| %>
  <% case manager_remark.decision %>
  <% when nil %>
    <td>Pending</td>
  <% when true %>
    <td>Approved</td>
  <% when false %>
    <td>Rejected</td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Taking it further it is probably better to have a method in the `ManagerRemark` model like this:

```
def decision_description
  { true => "Approved", false => "Rejected", nil => "Pending" }.fetch(decision)
end
```

and just call that method in the view like this:

```
<% project_site.manager_remarks.each do |manager_remark| %>
  <td><%= manager_remark.decision_description %></td>
<% end %>
```

Update: I misunderstood the question and now it seems like the OP wants to show "Pending" not when the `decision` is `nil` but there is no `remark` at all. In that case, I would do something like this:

```
<% if project_site.manager_remarks.any? %>
  <% project_site.manager_remarks.each do |manager_remark| %>
    <td><%= manager_remark.decision ? 'Approved' : 'Rejected' %></td>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <td>Pending</td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hi i its still unable to show "pending" status. there are two model one for ProjectSite another ManagerRemark. linked in a way one project site has multiple decision(status). decision attribute is in ManagerRemark model. it only shows approved(true) and rejected(false) value that is set by manager in ManagerRemark Model.

Comment: What does that mean if there is no manager remark (the Pending state)? Is there no manager remark for a specific manager or it there a remark but its decision in nil?

Comment: hi when ManagerRemark model decision value is set by manager on each ProjectSite, then only it shows decision(status) as approved, rejected, but on creation of ProjectSite i want it's status should be shown as pending..

Comment: I am sorry, I still do not get it. "Pending" means that there is no `manager_remark` at all in the database? Not a single one? Or is it missing for a specific manager (is there a list of all managers)? Or it is missing for the current user?

Comment: yeah "pending" means their is no manager_remark in database for each project_site.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if project_site.manager_remarks.empty? do %>
  <td><%= "Pending" %></td>
<% else %>
  <% project_site.manager_remarks.each do |manager_remark| %>
    <% if manager_remark.decision == false %>
      <td><%= 'Rejected' %></td>
    <% elsif manager_remark.decision == true %>
      <td><%= "Approved" %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td><%= "Pending" %></td>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my opinion, boolean attribute should have values, which only include `true` or `false`, if you want more statuses, `enum` is good choice.

References

- https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: this code throws syntax error- index.html.erb:28: else without rescue is useless '.freeze; else ^~~~

Comment: oh, sorry, remove `do` at first line.

`<% if project_site.manager_remarks.empty? %>`